# How can I convert fraction to double or decimal?

Tags: c#

Case:

```
double x = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(0.07003 + 1 ),(1/12));
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Output:

```
1
```

The above output is incorrect, because the result of `x` is `1` instead of `1.005657`

How to convert `1/12` in a format that it gives fractional value and is accepted by `Math.Pow()`.

And the real problem is division of `1` by `12` (`1/12`) which gives value `0` (instead of `0,083333...`).

Comment: Have you tried `1.0/12` or `((double)1)/12`? You should be able to just do:
`Math.Pow(1.07003, 1.0/12);` :)

Comment: 1.0/12 is the way! :-) thanks very much!

Comment: Can you please tell me why is it this way (1.0/12)

Comment: Yep, normal integer division returns an int. In maths lingo, it returns floor(a/b). In order to do proper float division, you need to force one of the inputs to be a float. In this case, 1.0/12 or even 1/12.0 will force float division to be used. [I've used "float" to mean float or double interchangably in the above]

Comment: Nasreddine's answer's even better - 12d forces a double, 12.0 is more of a work around.

Comment: Thanks David! I understand your point. Just confused because POW takes two arguments and both are double - Math.Pow(double x, double y).

Comment: @wafers It's because the `1/12` is evaluated before calling the `Math.Pow` method. After getting the result of the division (which is an integer at this point) an [implicit conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) occurs then the method is called with the double value of `0`.

Comment: Indeed, but by the time `Math.Pow` takes the argument, it's already 0.. ie the following occurs:
`Math.Pow(1.07003, 1/12);` => `Math.Pow(1.07003, 0);` => `Math.Pow(1.07003, 0d);` => `1d`
Where the middle arrow denotes an implicit type conversion from integer to double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
double x = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(0.07003 + 1 ),(1/12d));
```

This makes `12` a double which makes the result of `1/12` a double. So instead of getting `0` from that division the result will be `0.0833333333333333`.

Answer (score 1):

The literals `1` and `12` are both integers, so `1/12` is an integer division, giving an integer result (0). Change at least one literal to `double` or `decimal` to perform a floating point division.

To make a number literal a `double`, add decimal places (e.g. `1.0`) or 'D' suffix (`1D`). To make it a decimal, add 'M' suffix (`1M`).